# Erro de codificação no SQL Server Docker

Tags: php, codeigniter, linux, docker

Meu erro é o seguinte:

```
Type: Error

Message: Undefined class constant 'SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8'

Filename: /var/www/html/api.dev/public/system/database/drivers/pdo/subdrivers/pdo_sqlsrv_driver.php
```

Meu DockerFile do PHP:

```
FROM php:7.1.9-fpm

# Additional tools
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    openssl \
    nano

# Common php-ext and requirements
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libpq-dev libz-dev \
 && docker-php-ext-install pcntl \
 && docker-php-ext-install session \
 && docker-php-ext-install phar \
 && docker-php-ext-install iconv \
 && docker-php-ext-install pdo

#####################################
# GD:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_GD=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_GD} = true ]; then \
    # Install gd and requirements
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev libfreetype6-dev \
 && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 \
 && docker-php-ext-install gd \
;fi

#####################################
# compression:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_COMPRESSION=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_COMPRESSION} = true ]; then \
    # Install zip, bz2 and requirements
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev \
 && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    bz2 \
;fi

#####################################
# FTP:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_FTP=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_FTP} = true ]; then \
    # Install ftp and requirements
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libssl-dev \
 && docker-php-ext-install ftp \
;fi

#####################################
# MCrypt:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_MCRYPT=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_MCRYPT} = true ]; then \
    # Install mcrypt and requirements
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libmcrypt-dev \
 && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt \
;fi

#####################################
# Mbstring:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_MBSTRING=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_MBSTRING} = true ]; then \
    # Install mbstring
    docker-php-ext-install mbstring \
;fi

#####################################
# PDO_MYSQL:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_PDO_MYSQL=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_PDO_MYSQL} = true ]; then \
    # Install pdo_mysql
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
;fi

#####################################
# PDO_POSTGRESQL:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_PDO_POSTGRESQL=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_PDO_POSTGRESQL} = true ]; then \
    # Install pdo_pgsql
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql \
;fi

#####################################
# Mysqli Modifications:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_MYSQLI=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_MYSQLI} = true ]; then \
    # Install mysqli
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
;fi

#####################################
# bcmath:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_BCMATH=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_BCMATH} = true ]; then \
    # Install bcmath extension
    docker-php-ext-install bcmath \
;fi

#####################################
# Opcache:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_OPCACHE=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_OPCACHE} = true ]; then \
    docker-php-ext-install opcache \
;fi

# Copy opcache configration
COPY ./opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini

#####################################
# xdebug:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_XDEBUG=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; then \
    # Install the xdebug
    pecl install xdebug \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
;fi

# Copy xdebug configration
COPY ./xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

#####################################
# composer:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_COMPOSER=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_COMPOSER} = true ]; then \
    # Install the composer
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
;fi

# Copy xdebug configration
COPY ./xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

#####################################
# tokenizer:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_TOKENIZER=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_TOKENIZER} = true ]; then \
    # Install tokenizer
    docker-php-ext-install tokenizer \
;fi

#####################################
# json, xml, dom xmlrpc, xsl:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_JSON_XML=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_JSON_XML} = true ]; then \
    # Install xml, dom xmlrpc, xsl, and requirements
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libxml2-dev libxslt-dev \
 && docker-php-ext-install json \
    xml \
    dom \
    xmlrpc \
    xsl \
;fi

#####################################
# openssl:
#####################################

#ARG INSTALL_OPENSSL=false
#RUN if [ ${INSTALL_OPENSSL} = true ]; then \
#    # Install openssl
#    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssl-dev \
#    docker-php-ext-install openssl \
#;fi

#####################################
# curl:
#####################################

#ARG INSTALL_CURL=false
#RUN if [ ${INSTALL_CURL} = true ]; then \
#    # Install curl and requirements
#    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libcurl3 libcurl3-dev \
#    docker-php-ext-install curl \
#;fi

#####################################
# Human Language and Character Encoding Support:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_INTL=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_INTL} = true ]; then \
    # Install intl and requirements
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ \
 && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
 && docker-php-ext-install intl \
;fi

ARG INSTALL_MSSQL_DRIVER=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_MSSQL_DRIVER} = true ]; then \
    # Install mssql and requirements
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
   apt-transport-https \
   && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
   && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/8/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
   && apt-get update \
   && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      unixodbc \
      unixodbc-dev \
      libgss3 \
      odbcinst \
      msodbcsql17 \
      locales \
   && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen \
   && pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv \
   && docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv \
;fi

# Clear package lists
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Permissions
RUN chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html
RUN chmod u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx /var/www/html
RUN find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx {} +
RUN find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod u+rw,g+rw,o+r {} +

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

Answer (score 0):

Você provavelmente tem o driver PDO errado na instalação do PHP. Executo o PHP / CodeIgniter em vários servidores Windows e tive problemas com os drivers errados ao configurar as coisas inicialmente.

Desde que você está em PHP 5.6, você precisa para garantir que o php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll OU php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll motorista está no PHP /ext/diretório. Em seguida, no seu php.iniarquivo, você precisará garantir que essas duas extensões não sejam comentadas:

```
extension = php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

Quando esses dois não forem comentados, verifique se as outras referências aos drivers do SQL Server estão comentadas. Se isso não ajudar, aqui está outro artigo para verificar: Xampp MS SQL server PHP 5.6 .

Após ajustar o arquivo php.ini, lembre-se de reiniciar o site via IIS.